# compiler design

Tags: compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning to Write a Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)

How to design simple compiler?
I want to design compiler for MCA project.

Comment: It is a dupe, but sometimes you want to encourage people :-)

Answer (score 9):

Read: [The Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)

Comment: Have you actually read it yourself?

Comment: Yes. Mandatory reading for Compiler Design course in my Computer Science program.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Answer (score 3):

You don't. 'Compiler' and 'simple' are mutually exclusive terms.

Comment: By no means. You can easily write a compiler for a small language inside a week. Most websites take much longer than that to implement.

Comment: You can easily write a website for small content inside a week. Most compilers take much longer than that to implement. :) Writing a compiler is one of the most interesting challenges I've attempted, so even though it's "not simple" (IMO), it's a worthwhile experience for someone interested in the subject.

Answer (score 1):

[Let's Build a Compiler, by Jack Crenshaw](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) , a little outdated, but could be useful ([here](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf) is the pdf version).

Also you *have to* see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler) with a lot of resources.

Comment: +1 for the PDF - I've referred people to the terrible text docs!

Comment: Actually, why don't you update the "lots of resources" main question with the Crenshaw info? It's a Wiki, so you should be able to do that (I think).

Comment: Noup, I can't, rep stuff :P, besides, that answer was already posted (it's the last one).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definitive list of compiler building resources on SO:

[Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)